# Как сделать чтобы при переходе в файл с Windows Forms скролы на переходили в положение по умолчанию?

Tags: c#, winforms

**Используется**
Visual Studio 2015

Файл имеет Windows Forms с набором:
- panel (со скролами);
- dataGridView;
- textBox;
- button;

Работаю с кодом в Visual Studio.
1. Во время работы, скролы на некоторых panel сдвигаю на необходимые расстояния, чтобы обеспечить доступ к нужным textBox и button.
2. Перехожу в файл с кодом "Form1.cs". Там корректирую код.
3. Перехожу в файл с Windows Forms ("Form1.cs" [конструктор]), чтобы подвинуть скролы, для доступа к следующим textBox, button.

**Проблема**
При переходе из файла "Form1.cs" в файл с Windows Forms ("Form1.cs" [конструктор]) Windows Forms на мгновение пропадает (наверное перезагружается), потом появляется и все скролы становятся в положение по умолчанию.

**Вопрос.**
Как сделать чтобы при переходе из файла "Form1.cs" в файл с Windows Forms ("Form1.cs" [конструктор]) Windows Forms не дёргалась и все скролы оставались как при последнем посещении?

Comment: странно, у меня ничего не дергается и не перегружается ни Visual Studio 2015, ни Visual Studio 2017. Возможно используете какие-то кастомные контролы или в load что-то делаете. Можете код дизайнера выложить?

Comment: @Алексей Обухов У меня обычно тоже всё нормально... Так.. иногда бывает... Вроде только второй такой файл... Раньше терпимо было, а сейчас поднадоело.. Код. https://codeshare.io/GqABNx

Comment: @Алексей Обухов Я часто бывает несколько раз случайно кликаю по скролу или форме или границе панели... Может, что включилось?